# cURL using $http in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a token from an API. My cURL command seems to work fine in my terminal, can't seem to get it using $http though.

Here's my cURL:

```
curl --data "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_KEY&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9999&code=AUTH_CODE" https://www.twitchalerts.com/api/v1.0/token
```

and

```
curl --data "access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&name=Kennan&identifier=IDENTIFIER&amount=50&currency=USD&message=TESTTESTETSTS" https://www.twitchalerts.com/api/v1.0/donations
```

Currently I'm accessing it like this:

```
$http.get('https://www.twitchalerts.com/api/v1.0/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_KEY&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9999&code=' + AUTH_CODE)
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
```

It's giving me a 404 though when using the code above. and console error like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.twitchalerts.com/api/v1.0/token?grant_type=authorization_code&c…ct_uri=http://localhost:9999&code=RhWKTP0GACyS6VkfSpVaOlrYTWmKyAKLSwJg2Ynq. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9999' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I'm expecting a JSON response. Something like this:

```
{access_token: 'loXk8FTOFwKfrLP3bGCnJldBxuGX03a03iQdxR8A',token_type:'Bearer',refresh_token: 'IXCGDha46Q4eHBKrijmAqUwScbsMSuBy9IopXp80'}
```

Comment: How you are making `$http` request ..Show some code.. Output what you are getting.. ?

Comment: It's not very useful to show the part that works if you don't show the part that *doesn't* work.

Comment: @Juhana  
sorry. i've updated my post now

Comment: @atulquest93 sorry. i've updated my post now

Comment: What output you are expecting.. Its response in json ? ?

Comment: @atulquest93 I'm expecting a JSON as response.

Comment: Just paste the URL with auth token you are trying too hit with angular js in browser ...and check whether its returning data or not.. I think there is some problem in the url..

Comment: You can't access that API from the browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a different domain from your localhost .. As your error shows `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` So, either the browser is blocking your request to be generated or the resource over server is not accessible outside the domain.

If browser is not making request.. Try this to bypass [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) . 
Or if resource is not allowing then you need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to true in file at server end.